# what does this stanford lirbrary mean? C++ simpio.h getInteger()

Tags: c++

i'm trying to understand this library that stanford uses for their CS course but i can't just use this feature in my CS course back in my home.  How do i emulate this feature? i was wondering is this a getline(cin, integer)?  or is this something to do with fstream?  The reason being, i'm trying to go through the lecture series at UDEMY.

Here is the definition.

> `int getInteger(string prompt = "");`
>
> Reads a complete line from `cin` and scans it as an integer. If the scan
>   succeeds, the integer value is returned. If the argument is not a
>   legal integer or if extraneous characters (other than whitespace)
>   appear in the string, the user is given a chance to reenter the value.
>   If supplied, the optional prompt string is printed before reading the
>   value.
>
> Usage:
>
> `int n = getInteger(prompt);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download `simpio.h` here: http://www.eecs.wsu.edu/~cs150/prog/libs.htm

If you can't or don't want to use the library, you could study its source code.

Comment: i understand that, but i would like to know what this function is doing :P

Comment: @numLOCK: You question already states *what* the function is doing. If you wish to know *how* it's doing it, look at its source code. If you have difficulty following the source code, pick up an introductory C++ book and read it.

Comment: found it!  thanks i understand now that i can read the source code for the libraries.